# Remove Jquery AutoComplete Cache

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

```
var CollectionForAutoComplete = new Array();
function AutoCompleteTextBox() {

    var data = CollectionForAutoComplete;
    //var ac = $("#setcommonelement_ElementName").autocomplete(data);
    //ac.disable();
    // ac.setOptions({ noCache: true });

    $("#setcommonelement_ElementName").autocomplete(data, {
        minChars: 0,
        width: 262,
        matchContains: "word",
        scrollHeight: 220,    
        cacheLength: 0

    });
}

function generateStringForAutoComplete(CommonElementCollectionlist) {
    if (CommonElementCollectionlist.length > 0) {
        CollectionForAutoComplete.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < CommonElementCollectionlist.length; i++) {
            CollectionForAutoComplete.push(CommonElementCollectionlist[i].ElementName);
        }
    }
}
```

in run time i have loaded the collection and the push the collection into jquery autocomplet. but cache is not to be empty. please tell me how can i clear cache...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#setcommonelement_ElementName").result(function()
{
    $("#setcommonelement_ElementName").flushCache();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#elementoautocomplete').bind("change mouseover click keyup", function() {
    $("#elementoautocomplete").flushCache();
});
$('#elementoautocomplete').autocomplete('archive.php', {  });
// write this out
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the cache length to 1:

```
$"#your_selector").autocomplete('/url/',{
  ...,
  cacheLength: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution :

```
$("#element").unautocomplete();
$("#element").autocomplete(newData);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#element").unautocomplete().autocomplete(newData)` work too?